# MMX SSE extensions for for loop

Tags: gcc, assembly, compiler-optimization, sse, auto-vectorization

I have GCC 9.2 compiler.
If i use MMX or SSE/AVX extension you will have you code run in parallel, so it will be faster.
How to tell the compiler to use this instructions
I have a code snippet i want to parallel:

```
char max(char * a, int n){
    char max = (*a);
    for (int i = 0 ; i< n ; ++i){
            if (max < a[i]){
                max = a[i];
            }
    }
    return max;
}
```

it generates code using SSE extension but don't use pmaxub 
why

Comment: You forgot to pass the proper architecture flag presumably. It does use `vpmaxsb` for me.

Comment: What flags do you pass during compilation?  What operating system are you compiling for?

Comment: I was going to post something about using OpenMP `simd` directives to give hints about vectorizing loops like this, but [my testing](https://godbolt.org/z/ecw3Hm) showed that when you do that to explicitly request that the compiler vectorize the loop... gcc doesn't, but only does when *not* using the hints and high enough optimization settings. clang does, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SSE2 is baseline for x86-64, so yes `pmaxub` is available.

But your code uses `char`, and **`char` = `signed char`** in the x86-64 System V ABI, and Windows x64.  Perhaps you're coming from ARM where `char` = `unsigned char`?  The ISO C standard leaves the signedness of char implementation-defined so it's a terrible idea to rely on it for correctness (or performance in this case).

If you use `uint8_t` like a normal person, you get the expected inner loop from GCC9.2 `-O3` for x86-64, even without using `-march=skylake` or anything to enable AVX2.  (**[Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlICsupVs1qhkAUgBMAISnTSAZ1QBXYsg4ByZAmbEA1AFtmADwjbdegFR7mpPXnp7aASnEB2WQAYAgnr97zfSNjPXEAZgARPQhLZlcwr19/Gn0IBwJ7UMi9Tyzpe3CAYSc80Jk5PFcPcR9/Ovq8KmjgrOLmcQBWaTxOiKrE%2BsH6lvCo9q6ejojwgaG692na/wWapL9iTAJVWkMTGdWVnwPJMIdkVmUsVoUCfHoAOgRw7FXldIAOAH0M4Ig3%2Bi%2BGWstnsjhc7lmfn%2BBEBuxCo2isXikL0KWi6UyCNyMwKYWKOxxcgq/VWczqjWaJlaNk63V6JKWZOGVIR4zpU32jLJhzWoTci15Gy2xB2wU53h5GmcQhAGg6GlItFlngVqFlhSJMj0SlU6jKYU4CoIyql0oA1iAwpJ7tx3mFbR0DQA2Dqed4ATkkTplGm4CqVGhVpDVGgVChAnlIxsDUtIcFgSDQBgADnh2GQKGZUCm05hiCBgJ7SFQ0wQ8%2BGIAAjE2kSsOXQAT1lhtISYMmHoAHlaKwmzHSFgjKJ2DX8BtkAQ8AA3TDh/uYYyYZDKMvNhXpTCsGusPCV4iNwoYTQtgjEPAGNfSmj0JhsDg8IQiMSa%2BQ7yvhyDS1DJyd0OcAWk7MI9H/Iw1CeSIdAUAB3TdWDDFQ1HvaUtzlf0axDYx3idf8nW4PRgGQZA9Hde5JGiXBCBIfVODsQ8c3TGjnD0DVyhkI0TWcaUEEwZgsHzCBzUtbh7k4O0xM4MJXU4Do3DcbhvVQv1SAvThPEjAMgxDMMIyjTi4xgRAUGzVN03ISgk1MvMCyLEtWDLYgK2rfs61oRs11bbN2y7Hs%2ByDQcnxHfsxyXScZznIMFyXFdj3XehN23Xd92IBtDywDzT3PS9izoRgWBHB9hFEFAXyEXcP0E4MfzwP9ZUAsIEN1ZCfXlRUMNlLCcLwgiiJIsiKPwIh9CkA06JM3NhpOSRmNY2R2L0mMuNIC0wjCe5Vo2zatp9ZTNNVWUdMjaMVSW1DJAVVT1La/ttIWk7pRnRyaqVbggA)**)

```
.L14:
        movdqu  xmm2, XMMWORD PTR [rax]
        add     rax, 16
        pmaxub  xmm0, xmm2
        cmp     rax, rdx
        jne     .L14
```

**[`pmaxsb` requires SSE4.1](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/pmaxsb:pmaxsw:pmaxsd:pmaxsq)**.  (SSE2 is highly non-orthogonal like MMX, with some operations only available for some combinations of size and signedness, targeting specific applications like audio DSP and graphics pixels.  SSE4.1 filled in many of the gaps.)

If you enable it, GCC and clang use it.

---

With just `-O3` and the baseline x86-64 `-march` default (and `-mtune=generic`), GCC auto-vectorizes with `pcmpgtb` (which is a signed compare) then manual blend using `pand`/`pandn`/`por` and the requisite extra `movdqa` copying that entails.  `pcmpgtb` is your hint that your code as written needs signed compare, not unsigned.  Clang does the same thing.

```
.L5:
        movdqu  xmm1, XMMWORD PTR [rax]
        add     rax, 16
        movdqa  xmm2, xmm1
        pcmpgtb xmm2, xmm0
        pand    xmm1, xmm2
        pandn   xmm2, xmm0
        movdqa  xmm0, xmm2
        por     xmm0, xmm1
        cmp     rax, rdx
        jne     .L5
```

**GCC could have auto-vectorized by range-shifting inputs to unsigned for `pmaxub`**, then range-shifting back to signed outside the loop, by adding/subtracting 128.  (i.e. `pxor` with `_mm_set1_epi8(0x80)`).  So **this is a big missed-optimization for this case** which could have kept the critical-path latency down to 1 cycle, just `pmaxub`.

---

But of course if you actually enable SSE4.1, you get `pmaxsb`.  Or AVX2 `vpmaxsb`.

You *could* use `-msse4.1` or `-mavx2` but usually you want to enable other extensions that more recent CPUs have, too, and set tuning settings.  Especially for AVX2, you don't want to tune for Sandybridge and older CPUs because SnB doesn't even *have* AVX2.  You don't want split unaligned loads and stuff like that.  Also, AVX2 CPUs normally also have BMI2, popcnt, and other goodies.

Use `-march=haswell` or `-march=znver1` (Zen).  Or for local use, **`-march=native` to optimize for your CPU**.  (It's identical to using `-march=skylake` if you have a Skylake, unless maybe it detects your specific L3 cache size or something.)